# Acra reporting using email

Tags: android, acra

I am trying to use ACRA to report unhandled exceptions in my app.

Gave permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".MyApplication">
```

gradle:

```
compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.0'
```

Extended Application Class

```
package online.hannuveda.transafe_rx;

import org.acra.*;
import org.acra.annotation.*;
import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;


@ReportsCrashes(formUri = "",
        mailTo = "akshaycjoshi@gmail.com",
        mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
        resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text)

public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ACRA.init(this);
    }
}
```

In my login button, I am deliberately creating an exception using this:

```
public void Login_Click(View v)
{

    int i = 12/0;
}
```

When this exception occurs, I see the toast, then the app crashes but I don't see any email in my inbox. Any idea what is wrong ?

Comment: Remove `formUri = "",` and try again

Comment: Sidenote: Neither of the permissions are required for email reports to work.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I've also a white email and not the exception report

Answer (score 4):

Remove `formUri = ""`, and try again.

If you pass both `formUri` and `mailTo`, it will first try to send it via HTTP to the endpoint `""` and use the `mailTo` as fallback in case there is no internet permission, but you do have the permission so it only tries to send it to `""`, and won't try to mail it.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, remove formUri. When you use mailTo in addition to formUri it send the email if there is no internet at the time of the crash.

Further, this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"/>
```

Is only for some apps, and I think you have to apply to use it. On newer versions of Android, you don't need that permission any more.