# ACRA working on emulator but not in real device

Tags: java, android, acra

I have implemented ACRA on my Android application following [this](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40045595/acra-reporting-using-email) tutorials.
I have achieved to send a mail to my mail account on my tests on the emulator that Android Studio use (in this case, a Pixel 3 with Android 10):

[image]

But, when I generate APK of this project and **try to launch it on my device**, it shows the TOAST message (saying that the application has failed and that is going to be sent a mail), but, **when my default mail application is opened, the mail is completely empty (with no subject and no body). I don't know what could be happening, maybe some permissions issue?**

I also use gmail as my default mail application in my device (Xiaomi Red Mi Note 4 with Android 9).

The permissions included in my Android manifest file (The first two are necessary for other things that the application do):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

My class Application to handle the Application context:

```
import android.app.Application;
import org.acra.*;
import org.acra.annotation.*;

@ReportsCrashes(
        mailTo = "xxx@gmail.com",
        mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
        resToastText = R.string.crash)
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ACRA.init(this);
    }
}
```

This class has been added in Android Manifest file:

```
android:name=".MyApplication"
```

I'm using ACRA version 4.9.0, and in my build.gradle file I have included this deppendecy:

```
implementation 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.0'
```

My Compile SDK version is 28 and I'm using Java 1.8.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late reply. The solution that I found consists on use Outlook app instead of Gmail app.

Comment: I used Firebase CrashReport